# The for loop overwrites or entries duplicates

Tags: shell, awk

Say, I have 250 files, and from which I need to extract certain information and store them in a text file.
I have tried for loop in the shell as following,

```
text= 'home/path/tothe/textfiles'
    for sam in $(find ${text} -name \*_PG.tsv);do
        #echo ${sam}
       awk '{if($2=="ID") print FILENAME"\t""yes""\t""SAP""\t""LUFTA"}' ${sam}
           done >> ${text}/metadata.txt
```

With `>` operator the output text file is overwritten and with `>>` the output text file is being entered multiple times or duplicate entry.

I would like to know where should I change to get rid of these issues. Thanks for suggestions !!

Comment: This question would benefit from a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: wrt `with >> the output text file is being entered multiple times or duplicate entry.` - no, it's not, since the `>>` is outside of the loop the output of processing all files will be appended to the end of the output file once exactly as your accepted answer would do if you used `>>` instead of `>`. wrt `With > operator the output text file is overwritten` - yes it is, exactly as your accepted answer is doing. So what was the question about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this with a single invocation of awk:

```
path=home/path/tothe/textfiles
awk -v OFS='\t' '$2 == "ID" { 
  print FILENAME, "yes", "SAP", "LUFTA" 
}' "$path"/*_PG.tsv > "$path"/metadata.txt
```

- careful with your variable assignments, there should be no spaces around the `=`
- use the shell to expand the list of files, without `find`
- pass the full list of files as arguments to `awk`, instead of looping one by one
- set the Output Field Separator `OFS` instead of writing `\t` to separate your fields
- redirect the output to the metadata file

I assume that your awk script is behaving as you expect - I removed the useless `if` since awk scripts are written like `condition { action }`. I guess you only want one line of output per file, so you can probably add an `exit` inside the block to avoid processing the rest of the file.